# make canvas image repeat scrolling upwards

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, repeat, autoscroll

So I've got a 600x2400 image I'm trying to make scroll upwards (character will be autorunning down the screen) and repeat. I've got the scrolling, but not the repeat. My question is, how do I make the image redraw for a second instance from the top and continue when I get to the end of this one? so far when the code gets to the end of the image, I just get a staggered repeat of the bottom section of the first instance scrolling.

JS

```
let canvas;
let context;
let secondsPassed;
let oldTimeStamp;
let fps;
let map = new Image();
let roadMovement = 0;
let increment = 2;


window.onload = init;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');


    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

function draw() {
    map.src = "map.png";

}


function gameLoop(timeStamp) {
    secondsPassed = (timeStamp - oldTimeStamp) / 1000;
    oldTimeStamp = timeStamp;
    fps = Math.round(1 / secondsPassed);



    roadMovement += increment;

    map.onload = function () {
        context.drawImage(map, 0, roadMovement, 600, 600, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        
    };

    draw();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
```

CSS

```
body{
    position: absolute;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#gameCanvas{
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="gameCanvas">
    </canvas>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Edited* added let for increment value so autoscroll speed can be changed.

Comment: I rolled back your last edit because the answer doesn't belong in the question. On this site, [we maintain a strict separation between questions and answers](/tour). If you've found the solution to your own problem, that's great! Please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) in the space for an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could draw the map image twice and reset the `roadMovement` any time it gets larger than the image height. That's when you know the whole image is outside of the canvas view.

Technically, you only need to draw the second image when `imageHeight - roadMovement < canvasHeight`, but it might not be worth it to optimize.

```js
let canvas;
let context;
let secondsPassed;
let oldTimeStamp;
let fps;
let map = new Image(600, 600);
map.onload = init;
map.src = "http://www.secretdoors.com/playit/resources/chessboard.gif";

let roadMovement = 0;
let increment = 2;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = 150;
    canvas.height = 150;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}


function gameLoop(timeStamp) {
    secondsPassed = (timeStamp - oldTimeStamp) / 1000;
    oldTimeStamp = timeStamp;
    fps = Math.round(1 / secondsPassed);

    roadMovement += increment;
    roadMovement %= map.naturalHeight;
    
    const y1 = roadMovement;
    const y2 = y1 - map.naturalHeight;

    context.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);

    context.drawImage(
      map,
      0, y1, map.naturalWidth, map.naturalHeight
    );
    
    context.drawImage(
      map,
      0, y2, map.naturalWidth, map.naturalHeight
    );
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
```

```css
#gameCanvas{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas">
</canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you, I gave your code a read over and it finally hit me! still some optimisation to be done and such but I've put the working JS in the edit :) Thank you! 
```

Answer (score 0):

What about placing the image as the background of the page directly in CSS?

Try this:

```
   body{
        position: absolute;
        width:100vw;
        height:1000vh;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center; 
        
        background-image: url('./map.png'); 
        background-repeat: repeat;       
        background-size: 100%;  /*scale the image at 100% of the page width*/
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work with the canvas element. The aim is to get the image to move upwards with an incremental variable, and I guess somehow add a second instance of the image directly underneath as the first one moves up, then when the first one is out of view, replace the x and y from the new old one, with the new one, and repeat?  It's for an autoscrolling game 